# dnsmasqの最新バージョン(2.83)へのアップデート方法について

Tags: rhel

[Dnsmasq における複数の脆弱性 (DNSpooq)](https://jvn.jp/vu/JVNVU90340376/) に対応するため、バージョンを2.79から2.83にアップデートしようとしています。
しかし、RHEL8にて `dnf update` を行っても、2.83は含まれておらず、2.79が最新となっています。

リソースが以下にある事はわかったのですが、RPMパッケージではないため、RHEL8環境下で以下を用いてどのようにアップデートをすればいいか、方法がわかりません。
http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/

ご教授いただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHEL 向けのパッケージとしては、少なくとも CVE-2020-25681, CVE-2020-25684, CVE-2020-25685 に関しては「脆弱性へのパッチを古いバージョンに適用する」、**バックポート** と呼ばれる方法で対応が取られています。

[dnsmasq 2.79-13.el8_3.1 - RedHat カスタマーポータル](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/rhel---8/x86_64/7441/dnsmasq/2.79-13.el8_3.1/x86_64/fd431d51/package-changelog)

> **2020-12-16 Petr Menšík pemensik@redhat.com - 2.79-13.1**
>
> - Fix various issues in dnssec validation (CVE-2020-25681)
> - Accept responses only on correct sockets (CVE-2020-25684)
> - Use strong verification on queries (CVE-2020-25685)

ソースコードから自分でコンパイルしてインストールすることも可能ですが、rpm パッケージと混在すると管理が煩雑になるためお勧めしません。

Answer (score 0):

[RHSB-2021-001; DNSpooq - Multiple vulnerabilities within dnsmasq](https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/RHSB-2021-001) および [RHSA-2021:0150](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2021:0150) で説明されています。2.79にバックポートされているので、記載されているパッケージバージョンにあがっているかを確認しましょう。